# How to Parse base64 in Front-end?

Tags: javascript, base64

So, as a beginner in MERN full-stack development, I am trying to practice by using OpenSea's homepage and project page as my targets. However, since I cannot obtain API authorization, I plan to create my own project database. Currently, I have stored one piece of data that contains two fields, profilePicture and coverPhoto. After converting the corresponding photos into buffers and storing them in the database, I retrieve them in the backend and convert them into base64 before passing them to the frontend via Axios. I have been trying to convert the base64 back into image URL in the Axios file for many days but have not been successful. I know that it is possible to store the relative paths of the images locally, but I would like to try to access the images directly (which I feel is more practical?).

Currently, when I use Blob to convert the URL, it produces a blank page, and when I use data:image/avif;base64,${coverPhotoData.toString("base64")}, it produces data:image/avif;base64,[object Object].

Below is the relevant code. Could you please tell me where the problem lies? If there are better ways or other issues, please feel free to let me know! Thank you for taking the time to answer!

my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const nftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  coverPhoto: {
    filename: String,
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
  },
  profilePicture: {
    filename: String,
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
  },
```

Saving Data

```
router.get("/collection", (req, res) => {
  const profilePicture =
    "/Users/kailinyang/Desktop/opensea/server/NFTdata/1/1.avif";
  const profilePictureData = fs.readFileSync(profilePicture);

  const coverPhoto =
    "/Users/kailinyang/Desktop/opensea/server/NFTdata/1/1.avif";
  const coverPhotoData = fs.readFileSync(coverPhoto);

  const newNFT = NFT({
    coverPhoto: {
      filename: coverPhoto,
      data: profilePictureData,
      contentType: "image/avif", 
    },
    profilePicture: {
      filename: profilePicture,
      data: coverPhotoData,
      contentType: "image/avif", 
    },
```

Retrieving Data and Converting to Base64

```
 NFT.findOne({})
    .then((nftdata) => {
      console.log(nftdata);
      const profilePictureBuffer = nftdata.profilePicture;
      const profilePictureBase64 = profilePictureBuffer.toString("base64");
      const coverPhotoBuffer = nftdata.coverPhoto;
      const coverPhotoBase64 = coverPhotoBuffer.toString("base64");
      nftdata.profilePicture = profilePictureBase64;
      nftdata.coverPhoto = coverPhotoBase64;
      res.json({ nft: nftdata });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Attempting to Convert Data Back to Image in Axios

```
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080";

const CollectionData = async () => {
  try {
    const nftdata = await axios.get(API_URL + "/collection");
    console.log(nftdata.data.nft.coverPhoto.data);
    console.log(nftdata.data.nft.coverPhoto.data.data);
    const coverPhotoData = nftdata.data.nft.coverPhoto.data.data;
    const blob = new Blob([coverPhotoData], { type: "image/avif" });
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // tried const coverPhotoUrl = `data:image/avif;base64,${coverPhotoData.toString(
    //   "base64"
    // )}`;
    nftdata.data.nft.coverPhoto = imageUrl;
    return nftdata.data.nft;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
export default CollectionData;
```

The results of the console.log() statements on lines 7 and 8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Jtp.png)